# Connecting to a Archer c50 repeater question

Tags: bridge

I turned my my TP-Link Archer c50 into a repeater. Per the instructions it said to turn off DHCP on the repeater. My W10 laptop connects with internet access no problems however the RPI can connect to the router but no internet access. Is there an easy fix for this? Thanks

Comment: Can you post the output of `ping -c 4 8.8.8.8` (ping Google's DNS four times, checks for outbound connectivity without DNS.) You might also want to post a link to the Instructions you used. Do you have a DHCP server on your network providing or just the one you turned off? I

Comment: What is an archer c50? Is it a Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @tobyd *Stevo* configured a repeater so there must be another access point that I guess will provide the DHCP server and the repeater is able to bridge.